# Mostrar un xml en un Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estoy intentando abrir XML en un datagridview, lo que tengo es esto, me abre xml costosos y mas largos pero uno creado por mi no me lo abre y me dice "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter= "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                result = reader.AsDataSet();
                cbohoja.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                    cbohoja.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                reader.Close();
            }

        }
    }

    private void cbohoja_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = result.Tables[cbohoja.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Comment: Es un código que he sacado viendo vídeos por Internet y quiero saber como tengo que crear el XML para que no me de el error ya que los xml mas extensos que me descargo de cualquier pag si que me van y se abren perfecto

Answer (score 0):

te comparto mi solucion y el xml que he creado:

Mi Codigo:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "|*.xml", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = ofd.FileName;

                dataSet1.ReadXml(filePath);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet1;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = "Persona";
            }
        }
    }
```

El XML:

```
<Persona>  
<Dni>172-32-1176</Dni>  
<Nombre>Victor</Nombre>  
<Apellido>Lima</Apellido>  
<Tlf>408 496-7223</Tlf>
```

Simplemente creo un DataSet y este se encarga de leer el archivo XML a partir de la ruta que le indico, luego añado el DataSet al DataGridView y le indico que lista del XML debe usar en este caso "Persona". Obviamente no esta atomatizado ya que tendrias que conocer el XML que vas a leer

Un saludo, espero que te sirva la respuesta y si es asi marca tu pregunta como respondida